# rspec .reload not reloading object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've added the following tests to spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do
  subject { page }
  .
  .
  .
  describe "user should be able to update username" do
    before do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in "Email", with: user.email
      fill_in "Password", with: user.password
      click_button "Sign In"
    end

    specify { @user.username.should_not == "New Name" }

    context "after filling in correct details" do
      before do
        visit edit_user_registration_path
        fill_in "Name", with: "New Name"
        fill_in "Current password", with: @user.password
        click_button "Update"
      end

      specify { @user.reload.username.should == "New Name" }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-notice', text: "You updated your account successfully." ) }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit account details" ) }
    end
  end

end
```

The first specify returns username "Person", but so does the second one after the reload:

```
1) UserPages user should be able to update username after filling in correct details 
   Failure/Error: specify { @user.reload.username.should == "New Name" }
     expected: "New Name"
          got: "Person" (using ==)
   # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:83:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

If I change any line the test fails, and I've checked the app manually and updating works. I've also tried calling just `@user.reload` before getting the name again.

What could be the problem? Should I be putting this code somewhere else?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but don't you have to specify the user when using `edit_user_registration_path`?

Comment: It uses `@user = current_user` for those pages so there's only 1 path.

Comment: `fill_in "Email", with: user.email` - why not `@user.email`?

Comment: Wow! Of course! I hate it when you stare at code so long you don't see the obvious. Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `@user` instance in this lines:

```
fill_in "Email", with: user.email
fill_in "Password", with: user.password
```

So, it should be:

```
fill_in "Email", with: @user.email
fill_in "Password", with: @user.password
```

Comment: I was missing this because I had a `let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }` above and so the code wasn't breaking :)